# PsExec requirements on local computer

Tags: services, windows-services, psexec, sysinternals

What **services** and **settings** are required to run psexec on local computer?
(e.g. `psexec -s -i -d regedit`)

Answer (score 10):

[paexec](https://www.poweradmin.com/paexec/) is open source and seems to have less requirements related to network, and thus is easier to run locally.

For example **File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks** which psexec does.

> paexec.exe -i -s cmd

([Source Code](https://github.com/poweradminllc/PAExec/))

Comment: I was also searching for psexec requirements because it was not working "on local computer". paexec solved it for me by not needing them anymore. It is a better tool for the job answer.

Comment: To be clear, your answer is definitely valuable. It's just that it would be much more suited to a [self answer](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) question asking about a good alternative to psexec -- not as an answer to this question. Doing that would get your answer more visibility and and help cultivate a better long-term Q&A site.

Answer (score 9):

At least the following **services** must be running on the computer (in order to use `psexec` locally):

- **Server** (`LanmanServer`) must be running

  - errors when not running: *"The network name cannot be found."*; *"The specified network name is no longer available."*
- **TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper** (`lmhosts`) must be running or set to manual startup (it will be started in the second case)

  - error when disabled: *"The network path was not found."*

However you do **not need** any of the following:

- services:

  - HomeGroup Listener
  - HomeGroup Provider
- "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing" settings:

  - Network discovery
  - File and printer sharing
  - Homegroup Connections managed by Windows
- network connection items:

  - Client for Microsoft Networks
  - File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks
  - Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver
  - Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder

(Tested w/ psexec v2.2 under Win 10 x64 v1607.)

Comment: Another point I'd like to add this to this answer is that the default `admin$` share must be present for psexec to work. If you have deleted the share (and disabled its auto-creation as per the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1347778/)), you will get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8lRV.png) in psexec.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having issue with `"The network name cannot be found."`; `"The specified network name is no longer available.`", like this, make sure Server (`LanmanServer`) must be running as said by Ogmios.

Also **make sure** you have `"AutoShareWks"=1` in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\` in `Microsoft Registry Editor` as some *Privacy Cleanup Tools* mess up with this value, else if you still having this issue, try to replace `LanmanServer` with a clean system registry.

**NOTE: I am not responsible if you mess up your registry, use at your OWN RISK.**

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I works like a charm in W7 Pro SP1.