# how to stop sharing for drives that marks as default share in windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I share a folder on windows desktop and try to access it with `es explorer` on an Android device that asks me username and password. after filling it and logged in I see all my pc derive in mobile, I don't share them, and then use `net share` command in cmd that see all of my drive shared and remark by default share. How can I unshare them?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually remove them by running :

net share c$ /delete

but they only stay removed until the next reboot. To prevent Windows from re-creating them automatically you need to edit the registry.

Navigate to :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters

then create a DWORD value called AutoShareWks and set it to 0.

(Note, you may see other posts online referencing the value to add as "AutoShareServer", however that is for server OSs, while AutoShareWks is for client OSs)

Comment: why this happened? will we needs it sometimes?

Comment: It's for administrators on networrks, so they can connect to the machines they manage.

Comment: Not worked. I'm using windows 10 and after restart it will bring them back. The only solution until now is disabling Sever service. I have this my concern because of virus attack. The virus spread itself with accessing other client across the network via c$ and copy itself into startup folders.